# How can I lower this function's time complexity?

Tags: java, big-o

**Problem:**

Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

I believe the solution I came up with runs in a time complexity of O(N^2), I'm currently working on both creating more efficient code, and identifying time complexities with a glimpse of the code. Any feedback and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(10);
        l.add(15);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(7);
        System.out.println(isKsumPossible(l, 17));
    }

    public static boolean isKsumPossible(List<Integer> l, int k){

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size()-1; i++) {
            for (int j = l.size()-1; j > i; j--) {
                if (l.get(i)+l.get(j)==k) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The given code of method `isKsumPossible` does not seem to have any time complexity because the size of the input is hardcoded to be 4. 2) Solution by @Bohemian with O(N) complexity and using `Set` seems to be the best.

Comment: It does seem to be the case that my answer will always have a constant time complexity until I remove the user input aspect of it, I reviewed @Bohemian's answer and determined it was the best solution as well since O(n)'s time is lower than the previous O(n log(n)) answer.

Comment: I removed the user Input and hardcoded list size of 4, now my answer should run on a time complexity of O(N^2) as I previously thought it did. thanks for the feedback @AlexRudenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one constant-time pass, ie O(n):

```
boolean hasSum(List<Integer> list, int sum) {
    Set<Integer> found = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i : list) {
        if (found.contains(k - i)) {
            return true;
        }
        found.add(i);
    }
    return false;
}
```

`HashSet` operations are constant time, and there are 2n of those, so time complexity is O(n).

Comment: I had to set a print(found) statement below the found.add(i) line to figure out how that condition worked for the if statement. And it essentially verified (based on the provided example) if (17 - i) was present on the HashSet.  you solved it using such an wise approach. That being said though, I can't help but wonder why the outputs of the printed HashSet went as [10], [10, 15], [3, 10, 15] and true. instead of [10], [10, 15], [10, 15, 3] and true as I thought it would behave.

Comment: @AnthonyMendezFrias the iteration order of a HashSet is undefined. However, change to using a LinkedHashSet instead to get insertion order iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the list using `Arrays.sort`, which is *O(n log(n))* and search for the element in *O(n)*, making the method **O(n log(n))** overall:

```
public class Practice {
    public static boolean isKsumPossible(int[] l, int k) {
        // O(n log(n))
        // Higher numbers to the right, lower numbers to the left
        Arrays.sort(l);
        
        // O(n)
        for (int i0 = 0, i1 = l.length - 1; i0 == i1;) {
            if (l[i0] + l[i1] < k) {
                // If the sum is lesser than the target, increment 
                // the current sum by incrementing the start pointer
                ++i0;
            } else if (l[i0] + l[i1] > k) {
                // If the sum is greater than the target, decrement 
                // the current sum by decrementing the end pointer
                --i1;
            } else {
                // If the sum is equal to the target, return true
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the usage - it splits the code logic and the I/O logic, making it testable:

```java
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers of your choice:");
        int[] values = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            values[i] = numberScanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println("Enter K value:");
        int k = numberScanner.nextInt();
        numberScanner.close();

        System.out.println(isKsumPossible(values, k));
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't let me upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation yet. But I truly appreciate the answer. Thanks for the tip about splitting the code logic and the I/O logic, it makes it look cleaner as well

Comment: @AnthonyMendezFrias But you can accept the answer.  Click the accept icon beside the answer.